# why are this 2 c language programs giving different outputs?

Tags: c, clang

We were given the task of creating a compound interest calculator. After I finished it, one of my friends sent a different logic for the same question, but we both aren't getting the same output, though both logics are correct.

Regarding the two code snippets, they both aim to calculate compound interest, but they use slightly different formulas. The primary difference is in how they handle the interest rate "r"

In the first code, it uses (r/100) for the rate.
In the second code, it uses (0.01 * r) for the rate.
**Take this as input
5000
3
2.5**
**First code**

```
// compound interest calculator
// r/100
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    int p,t;
    float r;
    scanf("%d %d %f",&p,&t,&r);
    float ci = p*(pow((1+(r/100)),t));
    printf("Compound Interest = %f",ci);
}
```

**second code**

```
// compound interest calculator
// 0.01*100
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    int p,t;
    float r;
    scanf("%d %d %f", &p,&t,&r);
    float ci = p*(pow((1+(0.01*r)),t));
    printf("Compound Interest = %f",ci);
    return 0;
}
```

I expect both programs to get the same answers but, I am getting same answers to only this input

```
1200
2
5.2
```

Comment: Can you give some examples of test inputs, and the outputs you get in each program? Which output do you think is correct?

Comment: Use `powf` or make your types `double`. Also, even then there might be some difference in output.

Comment: @cafce25 I don't believe that's a good duplicate - the cause of the differences in this question aren't because the inherent imprecision of floating point calculations but rather the two code examples use different types to do the calculations.  The first example is done mostly in `float`, while the second is done almost entirely as `double`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, so it's about the inherent limited precision of `float` as compared to `double`‽ As you say yourself "even [using 0.01F is] different from dividing a float by 100"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 2):

The calculations are done differently because you use different types.

Given

```
float r;
```

the value

```
r / 100
```

will be calculated as a `float`.  And therefore

```
1 + ( r / 100 )
```

will also be calculated as a `float`, then passed to `pow` after it gets promoted to a `double`.

But the literal value `0.01` is a `double` in C, so

```
0.01 * r
```

will cause `r` to be promoted to `double`.

Likewise, that means

```
1 + ( 0.01 * r )
```

will also then be calculated as a `double`.

Those differences can and will cause different results.

Comment: ...and so a good recommendation would be to use `double` instead of `float` in code like that in the question.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Or `0.01F` instead of a bare `0.01`.  But even that's different from dividing a `float` by 100.

Comment: Another difference is the `0.01` which can't be exactly represented in either `float` or `double`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle So, how can we correct the second code?

Comment: @MoovvaChennaKesav  Neither code needs to be corrected, neither result is more "correct" than the other.  If you want the same results using floating point calculations, you have to be careful to do the calculations the same way, using the same variable types.  And compile the code the same way.  And be very careful about the optimization options you pass to your compiler.

Comment: OK, thank you all for explaining About the codes